# THREE.js: merging indexed geometries into buffer geometry

Tags: three.js, buffer

I'm trying to merge a large amount of indexed geometries (like SphereGeometry) into a single buffer geometry.

The indexed geometry is my 'prefab'.

First, I 'flatten' the indices of the prefab into an array like this:

```
var prefabFaceCount = prefabGeometry.faces.length;

for (var i = 0; i < prefabFaceCount; i++) {
    var face = prefabGeometry.faces[i];
    prefabIndices.push(face.a, face.b, face.c);
}
```

Then, I repeat the indices with an offset for each prefab, like this:

```
var prefabIndexCount = prefabGeometry.faces.length * 3;
var prefabVertexCount = prefabGeometry.vertices.length;

for (var i = 0; i < prefabCount; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < prefabIndexCount; k++) {
        bufferIndices[i * prefabIndexCount + k] = prefabIndices[k] + i * prefabVertexCount;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I have less than 65535 faces (prefabFaceCount * prefabCount), but when I exceed this number, my indices get messed up, resulting in incorrect triangles.

This is with less than 65535 faces
[image: correct indices]

This is with more (note the artifact in the center)
[image: incorrect indices]

This is more pronounced when I'm buffering more complex geometries like SphereGeometries (the spheres should not be connected):

[image: even more incorrect indices]

My guess is that the problem occurs when the buffergeometry is chunked into offsets by calling BufferGeometry.computeOffsets(). I have tried different combinations of chunk sizes and index ordering, but I have not yet found the solution.

Do I have to:

a) account for chunk size when buffering the indices

b) calculate the chunk size based on the number of faces in my 'prefab'

c) do a combination of a and b

d) do something else entirely

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [OES_element_index_uint](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index attribute is stored in Uint16Array

Uint16 cannot reference to a position higher than 65535 because it will overflow (uint16 goes just to 2^16)

easiest is to change the index attribute buffer to a Uint32Array as LJ suggested

(browser needs to support OES_element_index_uint extension, but most browsers do)

Comment: Thanks. Using an Unit32Array does fix the issue (I forgot I had to change the actual array declaration), but I may have to implement a fallback for browsers that do not support the extension. What would be the approach to calculate the correct index buffer sizes/offsets/indices ... numbers?

Comment: easy way would be to divide your geometry so every has only up to 65535 positions (so the position attribute buffer length is less than 65535*3)

Comment: the hard way would be to merge the buffer geometry by yourself so that you have indices only up to 65535 and when you need to reference higher position you just create another drawcall from that offset and start indexing from there, that actually creates as much draw calls to webGL as having more geometries and is too hard to implement for the small performance gain it brings

Comment: by the way you can check extension support [here](http://webglstats.com/) OES_element_index_uint is supported by well over 95% of browsers